# Adding an external class with the same package name and breaking encapsulation

Tags: java, encapsulation, access-modifiers, package-private

I've run into this statement when I was reading a book on Kotlin:

> With Java, the encapsulation can be easily broken, because external code can define classes in the same packages used by your
>   code and thus get access to your package-private declarations...

I'm not sure if I get this totally correct but does it mean can I somehow define a class in the same package with, for example, a third-party module that I depend on and then access it's package-private data? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: Simple understanding, you have MyClass code in your program in java, you use an external package that somehow(or more likely made to have)  a class with the same name MyClass name inside it.  That class will have access to all data inside your MyClass even if its private

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying but what I'm asking has nothing to do with having two classes with the same name. I'm asking if it's possible to EXTERNALLY define a class within the same package of a library module (lets say a jar file) which I already use in my code and thus be able to access package-private data of that library module.